# Como conseguir Colocar o texto de uma textBox numa Label? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em C# WPF, e tenho dois forms.

Um Form tem várias labels (com o nome de vários campos, como idade genero, nome, etc...) e debaixo de cada uma das labels tem uma TextBox para inserir um valor para a mesma.

No form seguinte eu tenho novamente um conjunto de labels com o nome dos campos, e por baixo de cada label quero ter outra label com o valor que foi introduzido na textBox respectiva no Form anterior, ou seja isto tem de ser conseguido de forma dinâmica.

Alguém tem ideia como posso fazer isto?

Tenho como auxiliares classes para os campos:

class:atributos

```
public class atributos
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int atributoID { get; set; }

}
```

class: valores

```
public class AtributosValores
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Basicamente eu quero apresentar no segundo conjunto de labels do 2º Form este Value, ou seja o Value introduzido na Text Box

Crio as textBox e Labels de forma dinamica tambem:

```
        public static Label createNewLabelSize (string name, int content, HorizontalAlignment horizontal, VerticalAlignment vertical, int width, int height)
        {

            //Create a new label
            Label newLabel = new Label();
            //Defines the new label characteristics
            newLabel.Name = name;
            newLabel.Content = content;
            newLabel.HorizontalAlignment = horizontal;
            newLabel.VerticalAlignment = vertical;
            newLabel.Width = width;
            newLabel.Height = height;


            return newLabel;
        }
```

Por isso coisas como label1.text = textbox2.text... não resultam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma lista de objetos da classe AtributosValores, percorra o Form localizando os TextBox, e adicione os objetos na lista. Passe a Lista para o Form2, e percorra criando os campos. Utilize a propriedade Name do TextBox como o nome do atributo (que é exibido no Label).

Exemplo:

```
public List<AtributosValores> ValoresForm1 = new List<AtributosValores>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LerValores(this);
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.ValoresForm2 = this.ValoresForm1;
    form.Show();
}
private void LerValores(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        if (c.HasChildren)
        {
            LerValores(c);
        }
        else if (c is TextBox)
        {
            AtributosValores obj = new AtributosValores();
            obj.Name = c.Name;
            obj.Value = ((TextBox)c).Text;
            ValoresForm1.Add(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Segue código alterado para WPF:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public List<AtributosValores> ValoresForm1 = new List<AtributosValores>();
        private void LerValores(ContentControl ctrl)
        {
            foreach (TextBox tb in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(ctrl))
            {
                AtributosValores obj = new AtributosValores();
                obj.Name = tb.Name;
                obj.Value = tb.Text;
                ValoresForm1.Add(obj);
            }

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LerValores(this);
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.ValoresForm2 = this.ValoresForm1;
            form.Show();
        }
```

Comment: acho que editou enquanto ainda estava a responder

Comment: Editei a resposta para adequar à sua edição.

Comment: é uma public List<AtributosValores> ValoresForm2 = new List<AtributosValores>(); porém dentro do Form2

Comment: no evento Load do Form 2, você percorre essa lista pra criar os campos

Comment: ctrl.Controls  com S no final

Comment: ok ok, estou falando de Forms e vc de Window (WPF), um momento

Comment: coloquei o código para WPF

Comment: mais algum codigo ?

Comment: não sei se aqui tem batepapo direto, mas chama no Facebook qlqr coisa